# Does IE need an element to be inserted into the DOM before knowing it's properties?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, prototypejs

I hope this is not an duplicate question, but a quick search didn't give me any results.
I need to create an `<select multiple="multiple">` element dynamically, using data like this:

```
var _options = [
    {
        MaterialCombined: '123 - asd',
        MaterialName: '123'
    },{
        MaterialCombined: '143123 - asdqw',
        MaterialName: '143123'
    }
];
```

Now, the following code works perfectly in browsers != IE

```
var select = new Element('select ', {'multiple ': 'multiple ','size ': ((_options.length > 5) ? 5 : _options.length),'class ': 'AF_ddl ','style ': 'width: 250px'});

for (var i = 0; i < _options.length; ++i) {
    var option = new Element('option ').update(_options[i].MaterialCombined);
    option.value = _options[i].MaterialName;
    select.options.add(option);
}
```

But in IE, it throws an exception when trying to call `add()` on the `select.options` property. Why is that? Does IE need the `select` to be inserted into the DOM before it can manipulate it?
Note, that I do have it working like this

```
var tmp = '';
for(var i = 0; i < _options.length; ++i){
    tmp += '<option value="'+_options[i].MaterialName+'">'+_options[i].MaterialCombined+'</option>';
}                                       
var select = new Element('select', {'multiple' : 'multiple', 'size' : ((_options.length > 5) ? 5 : _options.length) , 'class' : 'AF_ddl' , 'style' : 'width:250px'}).update(tmp);
```

But I really don't like this way of handling my elements! :(

Comment: I am using Prototype - don't think there's an `new Element('type', {..properties..})` element constructor in the basic DOM :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the message given by the exception? You could try the alternate method of adding `<option>` elements to the collection by swapping the line

```
select.options.add(option);
```

with

```
select.options[i] = option;
```

---

Edit: *or* you can use `appendChild()`:

```
select.appendChild(option);
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mc8s5/**

Note that IE9 in compat mode was having trouble with the element itself, because of the spaces following the tag name and attribute names in your code.  I removed these in the working example above.

Comment: Throws an invalid argument exception.. Have tried doing what you suggest, with the result of another exception being thrown (Object does not support this property or method - it's in danish, so not sure if that's what it says in english)..

Comment: @freaktm: Yes, that error message is all too familiar to me, a perfect translation.  See my update on how to solve your problem :-)